# помогите, почему не работает перевод из 16 в 10 систему

Tags: c++

при вводе числа AA в 16и ричнной системе выдаёт не 170 а 160

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
int first, sec;
char a;
int res = 0;
string d1, d2;
cin >> first >> d1 >> sec;
int razmer = d1.size();
char *f = new char[d1.size()];
int i, j, dop;
int B[26];

dop = 10;//A,B,C...
for (a = 'A'; a <='Z'; a++) {//то на что умножаем 
    B[a] = 0;
    B[a] = B[a] + dop;
    dop++;
    }
n = 0;
for (i = (razmer - 1); i >= 0; i--) { //делаем так чтобы последний символ 
находился в первом элементе массива
    f[i] = (char)d1[(n)];
    n++;
}
cout<<f[0] << f[1] << f[2]<<"\n";

int m = 0;

for (i = 0; i < d1.size(); i++) {

    if ((f[i] >= 'A') && (f[i] <= 'Z')) {
        res = res + (B[f[i]] * pow(first, m));

        cout << B[f[i]] * pow(first, m);
        m++;
    }else

    if ((f[i] >= 0) && (f[i] <= 9)) {
        res = res + f[i] * pow(first, m);
        m++;

    }


}


cout << "\n" << res;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте отладчик

Comment: Строка cout << B[f[i]] * pow(first, m); и должна выдать 160, а cout << "\n" << res;- 170

Comment: Опишите алгоритм, по которому вы хотите решить задачу. А то не понятно для чего у вас все эти переменные. Плюс ошибка: вы объявляете массив B из 26 элементов, индексацию по массиву вы ведете начиная с ASCII кода символа 'A', а это, 65. То есть, вы пытаетесь обратиться к 65 (и дальше) элементу массива, а это не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам не принципиальна алгоритмистика, то можно и так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long number;

    std::cout << "input number in hex: ";
    std::cin >> std::hex >> number;
    std::cout << "output number in dec: " << number << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```